# silverlight "initparams", key value, cannot load value

Tags: silverlight, parameters, init

have a initparams in html object:

```
<param name="initParams" value="location=images/images.xml" />
```

is it correct way to set location?

in MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);

            client.DownloadStringAsync( new Uri(Location, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));



 void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            string xml = e.Result;
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

in line  `string xml = e.Result` 
flying TargetInvocationException.

has some any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what your are trying to achieve with the code you provided, but the only way to retrieve the initParams (as I know) is in the Application_Startup.

That function has a StartupEventArgs that contains the InitParams as a Dictionary.

So you can retrieve your parameter value using that code below :

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
   this.RootVisual = new SilverlightApplication4.foo.SilverlightControl1();

   String imageLocation = e.InitParams["location"];
}
```

Comment: They are also available any time as `System.Windows.Application.Current.Host.InitParams`.

Comment: I didn't knew that!  Thanks for the tip! :)